# Connect my computer to a Reliance Netconnect device

Tags: windows-xp

I have a Reliance Netconnect modem.  How do I use it to connect my PC to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

[How To Connect To Internet Automatically With Reliance NetConnect Broadband](http://www.technixupdate.com/how-to-connect-to-internet-automatically-with-reliance-netconnect-broadband-on-your-computer/)
Maybe an overkill, but should work for you.

Further reading: [Hacking Tips for Reliance Netconnect](http://bnura.blogspot.com/2007/08/hacking-tips-for-reliance-netconnect.html).

<sup>And have you considered calling customer support?</sup>